# How to assign user activity task to all members of a team?

Tags: websphere, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I would like to assign an user activity to all members of a team, so every member will receive the activity and act.

[image: assigning activity to a specific team]

I've been using multi-instance loop, but dunno what to set in Start quantity so that all team members that the task is assigned for, to run the activity in parallel.

[image: multi-instalce loop ibm bpm]

Answer (score 0):

So, based on what you wrote what you actually want is N tasks, where each task is assigned to a specific person on the team you are targeting.  This is different than assigning to a team as if you assigned all N tasks to the team, one person on the team could claim and close all the tasks created for the instance.

Assuming you know the Team, you can use the "members" to get the array of people on the team.  You can use the array length to know how many instances you are creating, and you would use the step counter to assign to the specific team member.

You can use the `tw.system.org.findTeamByName()` call to get the team object.

Comment: I've managed this trying to find a solution by assigning a Team to the User Task and setting Round robin algorithm for User distribution. 
On Multi-Instance loop, I've set the Start quantity listLength of a variable (NameValuePair) which holds all team users.